# Angular + RxJS: How to make parallel request for each item in an array?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular11, mergemap

I have an array of IDs. For eg: [1,2,3,4].

I would like to make parallel calls and get the result with `forkJoin` for each element of the array. But below code is not working for me.

```js
forkJoin(
  Array.from(this.question.attachments).map(attachment => {
    return mergeMap((attachment) => ) // i am stuck here.
  })
)
.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  finalize(() => this.spinnerService.hide())
)
.subscribe((attachmentIds) => {
  this.uploadedAttachments = attachmentIds;
  this.onFilesAttached.emit(this.uploadedAttachments);
});
```

Can anyone help me how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. `forkJoin` function expects an array or object of observables. So you only need to return the observable from the `Array#map` function. HTTP calls using Angular `HttpClient` returns an observable by default. So there is no need for the `mergeMap` operator.

Also the usage of `mergeMap` is wrong here. It returns an [`OperatorFunction`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/OperatorFunction) and not an [observable](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable).

Try the following

```js
forkJoin(
  Array.from(this.question.attachments).map(attachment => 
    this.someService.getIds(attachment)                    // <-- return the HTTP call here
  )
).pipe(
  ...
```

---

Also in case if you weren't aware, an arrow function with a single statement without curly braces returns the statement by default.

So the following

```js
Array.from(this.question.attachments).map(attachment => 
  this.someService.getIds(attachment)
)
```

is same as writing

```js
Array.from(this.question.attachments).map(attachment => {
  return this.someService.getIds(attachment);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
forkJoin(
  Array.from(this.question.attachments).map(attachment => {
    return of(attachement); // return an observable here
  })
)
.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  finalize(() => this.spinnerService.hide())
)
.subscribe((attachmentIds) => {
  this.uploadedAttachments = attachmentIds;
  this.onFilesAttached.emit(this.uploadedAttachments);
});
```